# Jquery not working in Chrome, and not as expected in Safari and Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Chrome 55.0, Firefox 50.1.0, Safari 10.0.2

Wordpress 4.7.1, Dynamik-Gen 2.0

http://codepen.io/grantsmith/pen/WROPXr

HTML

```
<article class="accordion">
 <section>
  <header><h5>When will I get my race pack with number and timing chip?</h5></header>
  <div class="accord-content"><p>You will get your race pack in the post around 2 weeks before the race.</p>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section>
  <header><h5>Is the course totally closed to traffic?</h5></header>
   <div class="accord-content"><p>Yes, the Course is completely closed roads, so no cars or pedestrians will be allowed on the run course. The town centre finish will be fenced from Regents circus right down to the finish line. There will be ample space on both sides of the fenced area for spectators and pedestrians on both sides.</p>
   </div>
 </section>
```

CSS

```
.accordion {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.accordion header {
  cursor:pointer;
  background: #004B92;
  padding: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00256C;
  transition: background 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 1.0s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: background 1.0s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion header h5 {
  font-weight: 300!important;
  font-size: 1.8rem!important;  
  color: white!important;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
}
.accordion .accord-content { 
  display: none;
  width:100%;
  color: #00256C;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.accord-content p {
  text-align:  center;
  padding:18px;
}
.accord-content .selected h5 {
  background: #00256C;
}
.accordion h5:after {
 content: '\002B';
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: right;
 margin: 0 5px;
}
.accordion .selected h5:after {
  content: "\2212";
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready (function($) {
    // run the accordion
  var allPanels = $('.accord-content').hide();
  var heads = $('.accordion header');
  $('header').on('click', function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $target =  $this.parent().find('div');
      if(!$target.hasClass('active')){
      heads.removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
      $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $($target).offset().top}, 50);
      }

  });

}) (jQuery);
```

Hi, it should be pointed out that I know nothing about Jquery, as will most likely become very obvious!

I am trying to build an accordion for a WordPress page, http://www.newswindonhalf.co.uk/half-marathon/faqs/. The code above in  codepen works fine whilst there. Once placed into WordPress / Dynamik, it no longer works as per codepen.

Issue 1: Get it working on all browsers

Issue 2: Remove the scrolling, as it currently leaves the page view

Many thanks

Comment: what errors do you get in the browser's console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have written it this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // run the accordion
  var allPanels = jQuery('.accord-content').hide();
  var heads = jQuery('.accordion header');
  jQuery(heads).on('click', function() {
      $this = jQuery(this);
      $target =  $this.parent().find('div.accord-content');
      if(!$target.hasClass('active')){
          heads.removeClass('selected');
          $this.addClass('selected');
          allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
          $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
          jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $target.offset().top}, 50);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the following error in console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at HTMLElement.acc.(anonymous function).onclick (http://www.newswindonhalf.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/dynamik-gen/theme/custom-scripts.js?ver=1.9.9:8:26). From what little knowledge I have, do you not need to declare you are using Jquery with wordpress?

Comment: Sorry i missed that you were using Wordpress. You are right, you'd use jQuery instead of $. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It may not be finding the target div (div.accord-content). That would make the error make sense. When you debug, does $target get set to an array of at least one entry? Can you add some html into the question?

Comment: If I understand correctly, apologies if I don't. On clicking a section header, the article class accordion, changes to accordion active. And console reports the above error.

Comment: Yes, so the jquery is executing correctly, it is something within the onclick function that is causing the error. The only thing that is potentially changing the style attribute (referenced in the error message) is the last line, the animate. Try commenting that line out and see if it works.

Comment: Commenting out the last line works! Thanks very much. I've updated the CodePen in case anyone else requires it. https://codepen.io/grantsmith/pen/WROPXr

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    // run the accordion
  var allPanels = $('.accord-content').hide();
  var heads = $('.accordion header');
  $('header').on('click', function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $target =  $this.parent().find('div');
      if(!$target.hasClass('active')){
      heads.removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
      $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $($target).offset().top}, 50);
      }

  });

})
```